# Using a file watch to refresh a log viewer using PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlistview, qabstractlistmodel

I've implemented a very simple log viewer in Python using PyQt4.

I am interested in using it to follow the execution of a program, so the list view has to be refreshed when a new line is appended to the log file.

Here is my implementation (without the watch):

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class LogEntryModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, logfile, parent=None):
        super(LogEntryModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.slurp(logfile)

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.entries)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.entries[index.row()])
        else:
            return QVariant()        

    def slurp(self, logfile):
        self.entries = []        
        with open(logfile, 'rb') as fp:
            for line in fp.readlines():
                tokens = line.strip().split(' : ')
                sender = tokens[2]
                message = tokens[4]
                entry = "%s %s" % (sender, message)
                self.entries.append(entry)

class LogViewerForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, logfile, parent=None):
        super(LogViewerForm, self).__init__(parent)

        # build the list widget
        list_label = QLabel(QString("<strong>MoMo</strong> Log Viewer"))
        list_model = LogEntryModel(logfile)        
        self.list_view = QListView()
        self.list_view.setModel(list_model)
        list_label.setBuddy(self.list_view)

        # define the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(list_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = LogViewerForm(sys.argv[1])
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

As presented, the application works as expected: open the file, parse the contents (split at `' : '` and create a list), and display the list using a `QListView`.

There is a `QFileSystemWatcher` class which emits a `fileChanged` signal, but I don't know where to `connect` it and how to trigger an *add a row to the data and refresh the view* event.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: I've used Qt C++ libs, I can only tell you that you should connect the QFileSystemWatcher signal to the slot you want, and then it will be called when the file changed. Later that just read the docs about QListView to add a row and refresh it on that slot. Remember that a slot can be a method of any object (in your case, a def).

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to python and pyqt, but this "works" here:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class LogEntryModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, logfile, parent=None):
        super(LogEntryModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.slurp(logfile)
        self.logfile = logfile

    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.entries)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(self.entries[index.row()])
        else:
            return QVariant()

    def slurp(self, logfile):
        self.entries = []
        with open(logfile, 'rb') as fp:
            for line in fp.readlines():
                tokens = line.strip().split(' : ')
                sender = tokens[2]
                message = tokens[4]
                entry = "%s %s" % (sender, message)
                self.entries.append(entry)

class LogViewerForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, logfile, parent=None):
        super(LogViewerForm, self).__init__(parent)

        self.watcher = QFileSystemWatcher([logfile], parent=None)
        self.connect(self.watcher, SIGNAL('fileChanged(const QString&)'), self.update_log)

        # build the list widget
        list_label = QLabel(QString("<strong>MoMo</strong> Log Viewer"))
        list_model = LogEntryModel(logfile)
        self.list_model = list_model
        self.list_view = QListView()
        self.list_view.setModel(self.list_model)
        list_label.setBuddy(self.list_view)

        # define the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(list_label)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_view)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def update_log(self):
        print 'file changed'
        self.list_model.slurp(self.list_model.logfile)
        self.list_view.updateGeometries()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = LogViewerForm(sys.argv[1])
    form.show()
    app.exec_()
```

But be aware that this is probably not a good way to do it. 
You might want to stream the logfile...
Maybe somebody more experienced can help out.